# how do I make sure I receive modified versions of my GPL software

Tags: gpl

the [What is free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html) page on the gnu.org web site states among others:

»*An example of such an acceptable rule is one saying that if you have distributed a modified version and a previous developer asks for a copy of it, you must send one.*«

I like this clause, but I do not know how to add it in my licensed software. I don't think this is included in any version of the GPL license, or did I miss something?

Comment: You're asking two different questions here.  Which one do you want answered?

Comment: oh, I did not mean to ask two questions (one of which quite huge), the first question mark was just part of the name of the web page I was referring to. I removed it.

Comment: it's not about the question mark.  Your first question is: "How do I make sure I receive modified versions of my GPL software?"  Your second question is "How do I add a clause to the GPL?"  Which one do you want answered?  The GPL already requires that, if you modify the software, you make the modified version available to other users anyway, so I'm not exactly sure what it is that you're asking here.  Do you want to be notified of changes?

Comment: Further, the rule you cited addresses the *manner* in which such changes are distributed.  Does it really matter *how* you get the changes, as long as you get them?

Comment: sorry, I don't see your point. I am author to a GPL software, I'm obviously fine with others using and making it better, I would like to be able to request all modifications made by others to my software. I am not sure this right is already guaranteed by the GPL license. my question is how to specify this in a legally binding way? (if not already there)

Comment: »you make the modified version available to other users« - this does not necessarily include previous developers, does it? (and the clause applies only to 'distributing' the software, not just modifying it for your own use, or internal use of the company where you happen to work.)

Comment: It includes everyone.  If you distribute software under the GPL, you have to make your software and your modifications that you so distribute available to *everyone.*  If you make changes to GPL'd software for internal use, and don't distribute them outside of your organization, you're not compelled to provide the software to *anyone,* including the original developer of the GPL'd software.

Comment: @Robertharvey I fail to find obligation to provide source to third parties in GPL

Comment: There's no "third party" distinction, unless you have no basis under the GPL, but you did say that you are the author.  Either you're a party to the license or your not; there are no third parties.  If you distribute the software, you are a party and are obligated to the license's terms.  If you do not distribute, you are not a party under the GPL and are under no obligations.  That's it.  The terms and conditions for distributing GPL'd software (both modified and unmodified) are in Section 2 of the GPL.  The manner in which such distribution can be provided is described in section 3.

Comment: I'm reading [the GPL](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.en.html) and I do not manage to recognize what @RobertHarvey writes. In particular, where does it indicate that »anyone who comes into possession of a copy« (5c) includes the people who had (or indeed contributed to) a previous (unmodified) version?

Comment: @mariotomo: Typically, only the people in possession of a copy of the software know where to ask for the source code. By that means, other contributors get included in the group "anyone who comes into possession of a copy".